# how to change usd to indian rupee in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9

I forget to change the default currency value at the time of magento installation, may i know how to change USD to indian rupee in magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 2):

To change the currency on the your Magento site. 
In admin panel, go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Currency Set up`.
you should choose **Base Currency** , **Default Display Currency** and **Allowed Currencies**